# Scroll on LazyColumn stop working on SOME devices when I have multiple OutlinedTextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

Jetpack Compose version: 2023.08.00, 2023.10.01, 2022.12.00(current on project)

Jetpack Compose component used: OutlinedTextField

Android Studio Build: Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Canary 7, and CI compiled APK.

Kotlin version: 1.9.0, 1.9.20, 1.7.10 (respectively)

Steps to Reproduce or Code Sample to Reproduce:

1. Install a debug or release version of the minimal reproducible project
2. Disconnect the device from the usb port.
3. Set the focus to one Input from the list.
4. Scroll until scroll stop working smoothly.
5. How do I create the list:

   ```
   @Composable
   fun ListWithTextFields() {

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .testTag("lazyColumn")
    ) {

        for (i in 0..100) {

            item(key = i) {

                Column(modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {

                    val valueText = "valueText $i"
                    val onValueChange: (String) -> Unit = {}

                    OutlinedTextField(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        value = valueText,
                        onValueChange = onValueChange
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   }

Stack trace (if applicable): NA.

Minimal reproducible repo: https://github.com/gerardoeg/compose_scroll_issue

Some Looms that might help: Jetpack Compose Scroll Issue - problem https://www.loom.com/share/eb24a064d0a54d68b7c3deebf80ea087

Jetpack Compose Scroll Issue - expected behavior https://www.loom.com/share/8df5285fb664421e9261252239c667a0

I already reported the issue to Google, but I don't have any response.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/313971435